# Include time stamp in QGIS Modeler message

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

When making a QGIS model, you can include a Raise message algorithm, which outputs text. Is there a way to include a the system time in that message?

Comment: use `now` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415511/how-do-i-get-the-current-time

Comment: This answer implements this in Python. I am looking for a way to do it through the Modeler GUI.

Comment: does it not take an expression?

Comment: It does, but QGIS expressions, not Python code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the (slightly weirdly named) "Pre-calculated Value" option and in its "calculation" the `now()` expression:

[image]

The value will be calculated in the moment the Raise Message algorithm is actually executed within your model's flow.